# How to process matrix kind of jasper report

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, reporting, dynamic-jasper

I'm using jasper reporting to display image in pdf.
Here's the template I'm using for this purpose.

```
<band height="130" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="141" height="130" uuid="9908dc5a-89f7-460b-98b9-521c7aec57b5"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="141" y="0" width="138" height="130" uuid="553c9f56-eb72-4f25-80b7-b315ba3a1dc4"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{productQrPath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="279" y="0" width="138" height="130" uuid="b7f4ad17-e6c9-4f9e-a969-2fed6c6b41c9"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="417" y="0" width="138" height="130" uuid="8d5156b6-5ebc-4681-9cff-b88b1e5e4afd"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
```

Basically I want my op in this format https://www.anony.ws/i/2015/09/16/2.png

But I'm getting this kind of https://www.anony.ws/i/2015/09/16/3.png

it's obvious why i'm getting this kind as i'm using same placeholder in a single page.
even after using  `JRTableModelDataSource` i'm not getting op.

```
   JRTableModelDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(tbProducts.getModel()); 
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, parameters, dataSource);
```

Please give me suggestion how i can achieve this.

### PS

I don't have enough repo to post image kindly consider link.

### EDIT

Even I tried with 2D array just for testing the confusion is how should be the template design.

```
String members[][] = 
            {
              {"Larry", "Curly", "Moe" },
              {"Manny", "Moe", "Jack"},
              {"Huey", "Dewey", "Louie"}
            };
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, parameters, new JasperDataSourceBuilder(members));
```